# Page redirects to homepage when i reload using CTRL + R in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

When I reload the page using CTRL + R or F5 or open new tab redirects to homepage always in angular 8.

My Routes setup is here

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: OrderComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'orders', component: OrderComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'add-product', component: AddProductComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'past-orders', component: PastOrdersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'today-orders', component: TodayOrdersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'schedule-orders', component: ScheduleOrdersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'edit-product/:product_id', component: AddProductComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'invoice/:order_id', component: InvoiceComponent },
  { path: 'accept-order/:order_id', component: SingleOrderComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'timing', component: TimingComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  // { useHash: true }
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload', enableTracing: false, useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My function to open a new tab which should not redirects to homepage

```
    const url = this.router.serializeUrl(
      this.router.createUrlTree(['/invoice', '8088299'])
    );

 window.open(url, '_blank');
```

auth.guard.ts

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
    if (!this.authService.isLoggedin()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
});
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

}
```

this.authService.isLoggedin() the function code below it's not HTTP request

```
 isLoggedin() {
    // `!!` returns boolean
    return !!localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
```

Comment: Could you add the code for AuthGuard as well.

Comment: Does this problem occurs with the route which does not have AuthGuard enable ? please share the AuthGuard code too for better understanding ?

Comment: how do you serve your application?

Comment: @RahulSingh Added

Comment: @TechnoTech Please check now

Comment: @Andrei ng serve --open

Comment: it seems the issue is your AuthGuard. it evaluates before your authService knows you are logged in and redirects.

Comment: Could you share your authguard

Comment: @Googlian it's already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to validate your token is valid or not in auth guard service then return the result with boolean and redirect to the appropriate page at the same time.

The auth service should be as below

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    constructor() { }

    public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        return token != null;
    }
}
```

Let's say you have some routes as below,

```
/product
/product/:product-id
```

Then your route should be initiated as below,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'product',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ProductComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: ProductIdComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

Using this way you can even reload, redirect or directly enter the URL in the browser and enter the dynamic page you need to redirect.

The product id page is accessible until you have the token in your local storage.

[image]

> This is not a good practice as you leave a big security hole on client-side auth validation, try to use some server-side auth validations with Promise and HTTP or JSON web token, even you can send the token to the server each time you send a request and validate from server-side before proceeding the client request.

Please check this repository to find your solution in details
https://stackblitz.com/github/aslamanver/angular-sample-authguard

Comment: Thank you so much it fixed my issue @Googlian

Answer (score 1):

`canActivate` method returns before the authService.isLoggedin() is resolved. You need to return the response once the **authService.isLoggedin()** returns a reponse. **Return an observable from your isLoggedIn method** always. Once you do that, your canActivate method could look something like this:

```
   

    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    
      constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
    
      canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):  Observable<boolean>| Promise<boolean>| boolean{
       return  this.authService.isLoggedin()
            .pipe(
              map(
                response => {
                  if (response === true) {
                    return true;
                  }else{
                       this.router.navigate(['login']);
                       return false;
                  }
                }),catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                  this.router.navigate(['login']);
                  return of(false)
                })
            );
        }
      }
```

Comment: It would be great if you add all the code at once. Anyways, could you please add the code where you are setting the item in the local storage?

Comment: localStorage.setItem('token', received_token);

Comment: With the minimal code you provided, the condition should be something like `if(received_token && localStorage.getItem('token') == null){
    localStorage.setItem('token',received_token)
}` .  How are you  fetching the received_token, btw?